# PHP - Escaping doesn't work for me?

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to do JSON in string, but I have to escape double quotes.. Here's the line `{\"assetid":".$assetid.", "floatvalue\":".$floatvalue.\"},`

Comment: Don't understand, If you want to escape then must escape all the `"`...

Comment: Yeah, I want to escape `"`

Comment: post your complete string.

Comment: It is my complete string.

Comment: what will be your expected string????

Comment: Build an array then `json_encode()`.  Why not?

Comment: There's `json_encode` function which will do all you need.

Comment: Or `$result = json_encode(compact("assetid", "floatvalue"));`

Comment: I have to escape in that string..

Comment: You need to give a lot more information. Why do you think your string needs to be escaped? it looks to me like you're mixing languages javascript and php.  what's you full use here? Show more code. Is this string surrounded by quotes? are you assigning the string to a variable? Help us help you.

Comment: Also, I suspect what you may need to escape it the content of your variables and not the string you're showing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data =
[
    'assetid'       => $assetid,
    'floatvalue'    => $floatvalue,
];

$result = json_encode( $data );
```

**EDITED**

```
foreach($floatdone['result']['items'] as $data)
{
    $assetid = $data['id'];
    $floatvalue = $data['attributes']['2']['float_value'];

    $swag[] = //YOUR MISTAKE, i guess, use $swag[] instead of $swag
    [
        'assetid'       => $assetid,
        'floatvalue'    => $floatvalue,
    ];
}

var_dump( json_encode($swag) );
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for me.. I have to use it in foreach loop.

Comment: show us your foreach loop and the code before and after. No one's able to help without knowing what you're actuall trying to do. The answer to your literal question is  {\"assetid\":\".$assetid.\", \"floatvalue\":\".$floatvalue.\"} but I bet that doesn't help. How are you populating your variables? Edit your question

Comment: `foreach($floatdone['result']['items'] as $data){
    $assetid = $data['id'];
    $floatvalue = $data['attributes']['2']['float_value'];
    $swag = array('assetid' => $assetid,
                 'floatvalue' => $floatvalue);
}
$jsondata = json_encode($swag);
var_dump($jsondata);`

Comment: so what's the value of var_dump? What's the value of $assetid, $floatvalue? Please edit your question! Don't you see the down votes?